# Map complex data access business logic with oData

Tags: odata, netweaver

I have a table in DB and I want show/edit data with oData.
I don't want simply expose rows with an EntitySet because my business logic add information to each field of each row:

Example. I have in DB a table with 3 rows:

```
k   c1   c2   c3   c4
----------------------
01  a    b    d    e
02  f    g    h    i
03  l    m    n    o
04  p    q    r    s
```

UserA can:

- full control(Create-Read-Update-Delete) on each field (not modify-edit the key but can delete rows)

UserB can:

- edit only 2nd row

UserC can:

- Edit only m, n and r

**How can I send this complexity using oData?**

1. How can I recognize the user logged ? (a sessionId string in the header of http GET oData EntitySet?)
2. In metadata can I expose different type of interaction with data?
3. If I want specify a precise CRUD information (UserB) how can I pass informaions? (using complex type?)

These are my questions. I like oData, particularly the full-descriptive concept of metadata, but it seems not marry with my complexity of data access.

Comment: Can you add three end points for each user? for example:

User A:   ~/usera/...
User B:  ~/userb/...
User C: ~/userc/...

If yes.  #1 is visible. For #2, you can build different Edm Model. 
For #3, can you share more about the precise CRUD information?

Comment: thankyou @SamXu! What do you mean when you say _three end points_ ?

Comment: I mean can you do as follows?

>config.MapODataService("usera", "usera", UserA_Model);
>config.MapODataService("userb", "userb", UserB_Model);
>config.MapODataService("userc", "userc", UserC_Model);